# flutter release apk crash on start in android

Tags: android, flutter, crash, signed

When I run the app in debug mode it works fine. But in the release mode, it crashes and gets the error below. Please suggest solution.

```
VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(248)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(84)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
 A/flutter: [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(268)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6
```

Comment: try run using this command and see what the error `flutter run --release`.

Comment: i try but not working @JohnJoe

Comment: Flutter Clean worked for me